# IndexError: string index out of range on equation cleaning function

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, error-handling

I have code to append `^0` to all the constants in my code so that if you had the string "3x^2+14+2" it would become "3x^2+14^0+2^0" however I am getting a IndexError and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. This is my code:

```
def cleanEquation(equation):
    equation = ''.join(equation.split())
    for i in range(len(equation)):
        if equation[i].isdigit():
            if equation[i-1] != "^":
                if i == len(equation)-1:
                    equation = equation[:i+1] + '^0'
                if equation[i+1] == "+" or equation[i+1] == "-":
                    equation = equation[:i+1] + '^0' + equation[i+1]

cleanEquation("x+14+y+14")
```

Whenever I try to run this I get:

```
IndexError: string index out of range
```

This is only a snippet of the function the whole function adds 1 to the beggining of every coefficient and also adds ^1 to every variable with no coefficient and those 2 parts work fine for some reason even though they have the same format is this part of the function. I can post the full function if needed.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: the `if equation[i].isdigit():` line

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(equation)):
```

uses the original length of `equation` as the limit of `i`. But the line:

```
equation = equation[:i+1] + '^0' + equation[i+1]
```

removes characters from `equation`. When `i` gets to the new length of `equation`, you get an error.

You need to use a `while` loop so you compare with the current length rather than the original length.

```
i = 0
while i < len(equation):
    if equation[i].isdigit():
        if equation[i-1] != "^":
            if i == len(equation)-1:
                equation = equation[:i+1] + '^0'
            if equation[i+1] == "+" or equation[i+1] == "-":
                equation = equation[:i+1] + '^0' + equation[i+1]
    i += 1
```

You could do the whole thing with a regular expression substitution:

```
import re

def cleanEquation(equation):
    equation = ''.join(equation.split())
    equation = re.sub(r'(?<=\d\b)(?!\^)', '^0', equation)
    return equation
```

`(?<=\d\b)` is a lookbehind that matches a digit followed by a word boundary, i.e. the last digit of a numb. `(?!\^)` is a negative lookahead that prevents matching if the number is already followed by `^`.

Comment: I tried this but now I just get a blank screen and the program never finishes. Should I post the full code of the function?

Comment: If the last character of the equation is a digit, the line after `if i == len(equation)-1:` will add to the equation. As a result, the loop will never end because the equation keeps getting longer and longer, and it always ends with a digit.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with your overall algorithm. I don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: You should probably do it by putting the result in a new variable, instead of modifying `equation`.

Comment: I am just trying to add `^0` to any number that doesn't have a variable attacked to it.

Comment: Why not do this with a regular expression replacement?

Comment: How does your code prevent adding `^0` after `3x^2`?

Comment: ...im dumb... how do you do that?

Comment: Also it prevents it because I do `if equation[i-1] != "^"`:

Comment: That only works for one digit, what if it's `2x^10`?

Comment: How would I use regex? I have barely ever worked with it before.